# Search by multiple criteria in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-performance

I'm new in ElasticSearch!
I would like to design the mapping optimally.
Currently, the first query for products assigned to specific categories in a specific variant takes a long time (about 5 seconds for around 40,000 products in elasticsearch with an extensive request for variants). The next query is much faster than the first one.

A sample pattern in elasticsearch looks like:

```
"id" : 1,
"title" : "product",
"price" : "1100.00",
"categories" : [ the ids of the product's categories],
"tags" : [ the ids of the product's tags ],
"variants" : [ nested type with properties: name, definition, maybe in the future availability dates]
```

Maybe someone has already encountered such a problem? Or maybe it could be better modeled?
Categories and variants as a separate index linked by a relationship?

Comment: Hi, Could you please add your mapping here? But generally, I think your problem is not because of mapping and query. The second query is so faster because Elasticsearch uses a caching system inside of itself. Do not separate indexes and link each other. You can use include and exclude if you want to omit some fields to be back in results to have light wight responses. As curiosity, Your storage is HDD? Am I right?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja Hi, I upvoted the answer but the question is not mine to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you are using the [nested data typ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)e for your variant field and nested data-types are known for their bad performance and please refer to [go-jek medium blog on trouble with nested field](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/elasticsearch-the-trouble-with-nested-documents-e97b33b46194?gi=f12ffd00e90) and see if you can apply the suggestions mentioned in the blog to optimize your search performance.

Also, your second request is faster due to Elasticsearch cache and mostly its [shard request cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html) which you can monitor and confirm.